# How to locate div load with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem in load div using href.in here I am using href link and change div for relevant link.but my divs load in page top.I want to load it in after 200px height.please guild me.

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a> 
<div id="1">test1</div>
<div id="2">test2</div>
<div id="2">test3</div>
```

code structure is like this.[image]

Comment: put your real source code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: add style padding-top:200px for each div

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lakshitha/g4xedh3m/

Comment: @user3415221 Actually, better edit the question and put the real source code in a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `href` of clicked anchor tag using JQuery [.click()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=click) and [.attr()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=attr) Methods. Then you will need to get the html by id and change the HTML of your required container by using JQuery method [.html()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=html).

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#1"><span id="1">A</span></a>
<a href="#2"><span id="2">B</span></a>
<a href="#3"><span id="3">C</span></a>
<a href="#4"><span id="4">D</span></a>
<br><br><br>
<div id="changed">Click on Links to see text here</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href')
      $("#changed").html( $(href).html() );
      return false;
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/a3Ln0x6v/

> Don't forget to include [JQuery Library](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js) in your web page before the JQuery functions like this:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        .......
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: In here you use to add content dynamically. but in my case statically I set content so no need to implement like this way.Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user3415221 actually, I have given you an example that how you can solve your problem. You can implement the same approach with your static content/html, the code should be remain same!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use anchors/bookmarks?

You can place a div just above your target content:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div class="content">test1</div>
```

If so you can offset the anchor div with some css:

```
#1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Play around with the top: -250px; till you get the desired offset. The resulting

```
<a href="#1">Click to move to position 1</a>
```

Should move to the content below with the desired vertical offset.

////

OR use jQuery (overkill for simple scroll offset but adds nice animation):

```
var offset = $('#1').offset();
var scrollto = offset.top - 60; // adjust 60 to desired height
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollto}, 0);
```